# /var/log/secure and other log files are empty even after restarting rsyslog.service

Tags: logs, rsyslog

I am running a `Centos7` server with `rsyslog` for logging. The service is on (`sudo systemctl is-enabled rsyslog`) outputs "enabled". I have also configured the service to start at boot-time.

However, the `/var/log/secure` file is still empty despite deliberate attempts to fail SSH login. The other log files (mailer, spool, cron except messages) are all also empty.

Where am I going wrong in this? Any help is welcome.

**Update:**
Output of `ls -ld /var/log`:
`drwxr-xr-x. 11 root root 4096 Mar  4 11:06 /var/log`

and output of `ls -l /var/log`:
`drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root        6 Oct  7 17:53 anaconda
drwxr-x---. 2 root   root       94 Mar  4 13:39 audit
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root      549 Nov 30 16:33 boot.log
-rw-------. 1 root   utmp        0 Mar  1 03:13 btmp
-rw-------. 1 root   utmp     1920 Feb 11 15:25 btmp-20160301
drwxr-xr-x. 2 chrony chrony      6 Nov 24 03:05 chrony
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    14056 Nov 30 16:33 cloud-init.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    34623 Mar  4 10:19 cloud-init-output.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root        0 Feb 28 03:40 cron
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root        0 Feb  1 03:09 cron-20160207
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root        0 Feb  7 03:09 cron-20160214
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root     8948 Feb 18 21:01 cron-20160223
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root        0 Feb 23 12:41 cron-20160228
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    35746 Mar  4 10:19 dmesg
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    35859 Mar  3 11:48 dmesg.old
-rw-------. 1 root   root     1948 Dec 29 12:08 grubby
drwx------. 2 root   root     4096 Mar  1 20:14 httpd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root   292876 Mar  4 15:59 lastlog
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb 28 03:40 maillog
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb  1 03:09 maillog-20160207
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb  7 03:09 maillog-20160214
-rw-------. 1 root   root     3583 Feb 18 19:07 maillog-20160223
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb 23 12:41 maillog-20160228
-rw-------. 1 root   root   120630 Mar  4 10:49 messages
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb  1 03:09 messages-20160207
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb  7 03:09 messages-20160214
-rw-------. 1 root   root    42189 Feb 18 21:03 messages-20160223
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb 23 12:41 messages-20160228
drwxr-xr-x. 2 ntp    ntp         6 Jan 25 19:57 ntpstats
drwx------. 2 root   root        6 Jun 10  2014 ppp
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root   root       25 Nov 30 16:55 rsyslog_custom
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb 28 03:40 secure
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb  1 03:09 secure-20160207
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb  7 03:09 secure-20160214
-rw-------. 1 root   root    17991 Feb 18 20:20 secure-20160223
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb 23 12:41 secure-20160228
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb 28 03:40 spooler
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb  1 03:09 spooler-20160207
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb  7 03:09 spooler-20160214
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb 14 03:34 spooler-20160223
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Feb 23 12:41 spooler-20160228
-rw-------. 1 root   root        0 Oct  7 17:43 tallylog
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root       22 Dec  9 18:55 tuned
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root   utmp   241152 Mar  4 15:59 wtmp
-rw-------. 1 root   root     1926 Mar  4 13:20 yum.log
-rw-------. 1 root   root    13145 Dec 29 16:02 yum.log-20160101`

Comment: 1. is `journald` configured to forward log entries to `rsyslog`?  2. is `rsyslog` configured to write log entries with facility `auth` to `/var/log/secure` - try: `grep auth /etc/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/*`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not know the `journald` part, so could you explain that a little more? There is only one line in rsyslog.conf which says: `authpriv.*    /var/log/secure`

Comment: Can you [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/267544/edit) your question with the result of `ls -ld /var/log` and `ls -l /var/log`.

Comment: @EightBitTony: Added more details. Does that help?

Comment: try changing `authpriv.*` to `auth,authpriv.*` and restarting `rsyslogd` - `auth` and `authpriv` are two separate syslog facilities.   BTW, on my debian system, I have `auth,authpriv.*    /var/log/auth.log` and all auth orisation messages go to `auth.log`

Comment: as for making sure journald is working with rsyslog, see http://www.unixmen.com/logging-journald-rhel7centos7/ or https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-interaction_of_rsyslog_and_journal.html or just google for `journald rsyslogd`.

Comment: @cas: I checked those links. Everything seems to be configured correctly. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration for `/var/log/messages` contains the line:

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none /var/log/messages
```

remove the `*`:

```
.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none /var/log/messages
```

then restart the `rsyslogd` (`systemctl restart rsyslog`). I don't know why, but I had the same problem and it worked.